Cannot mute/unmute microphone in Wayland
Fristly I want to say that I tested multiple distros like Arch, Manjaro, now I installed fresh Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and my issue is happening same as on Arch-based distros.
So my issue is that I cannot toggle microphone under Wayland, neither via keyboard shortchut, or via GUI or via CLI command. Under X11 it works just fine, but I want to move to Wayland, so I wish I could fix this issue.
There is video of that happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WfaewkADog
Same happens when I go to GNOME keyboard shortcut settings and bind some keyboard button for mic toggle, nothing happens it just keeps same value, not muting or unmuting.
Then I tried to run cli command amixer set Capture toggle, as shown on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPMooCkuKC4
As you can see on it, 90% of cases it never mutes/unmutes.
I tried even commands like:
pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle

amixer -qD default sset 'Capture' toggle

Still happening.
I tried to change DE in GDM login screen and I found that:

GNOME on X11 works.
GNOME on Wayland doesnt work.
Weston works.

Hardware:
As sound card I use external USB sound card Sound Blaster Play! 2, now I tried regular internal sound card on motherboard and it works just fine, problem is with that combo GNOME + Wayland + Soundblaster, but I want to use that external sound card, because it has much better noise cancellation out of box + better quality.
lsusb -vt says this:
lsusb -vt
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 007: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 007: Dev 002, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 007: Dev 002, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 007: Dev 002, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=[none], 12M
        ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 008: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=[none], 12M
        ID 08e6:3437 Gemalto (was Gemplus) GemPC Twin SmartCard Reader
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
        |__ Port 003: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            ID 041e:323d Creative Technology, Ltd
        |__ Port 003: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            ID 041e:323d Creative Technology, Ltd
        |__ Port 003: Dev 004, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            ID 041e:323d Creative Technology, Ltd
        |__ Port 003: Dev 004, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 041e:323d Creative Technology, Ltd
        |__ Port 004: Dev 010, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 480M
            ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (charging + debug)
    |__ Port 002: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
        |__ Port 001: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
            |__ Port 003: Dev 007, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
                ID 20bc:502e ShenZhen ShanWan Technology Co., Ltd.
        |__ Port 003: Dev 006, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0060 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0213 Gaming Mouse [Lancehead Tournament Edition]
        |__ Port 003: Dev 006, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0060 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0213 Gaming Mouse [Lancehead Tournament Edition]
        |__ Port 003: Dev 006, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0060 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0213 Gaming Mouse [Lancehead Tournament Edition]
        |__ Port 004: Dev 008, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0221 Razer USA, Ltd RZ03-0203 Gaming Keyboard [BlackWidow Chroma V2]
        |__ Port 004: Dev 008, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0221 Razer USA, Ltd RZ03-0203 Gaming Keyboard [BlackWidow Chroma V2]
        |__ Port 004: Dev 008, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            ID 1532:0221 Razer USA, Ltd RZ03-0203 Gaming Keyboard [BlackWidow Chroma V2]
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
    |__ Port 002: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
/:  Bus 005.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0c76:1711 JMTek, LLC.
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0c76:1711 JMTek, LLC.
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        ID 0c76:1711 JMTek, LLC.
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 0c76:1711 JMTek, LLC.
/:  Bus 006.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


Where in the question does it say what the mic hardware is or how it is connected? Please update the question with edit and add this critical info.

@DavidDE I added it into hardware section

The toggle commands work in X11 but not in Wayland? amixer sset Capture toggle should work independent from any window system. Assuming the command works the question boils down on how to keybind keys to a command, since that depends if X11 or Wayland is running
